# Instagram liking a photo using php, curl or json

Tags: php, curl, instagram

I'm writing an instagram web app and i'm looking at Instagrams developer details and I'm at a stage where I'm stuck.

I am using json to retrieve images for my feed, I've managed to log into my instagram app.

Now what I'd like to do is be able to view images and 'like' them. Instagram only seem to show me the following details

```
curl -F 'access_token=11208672.f59def8.d78b9193a13d4e79a5bdb985ce73831d' \
    https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/likes
```

Could someone assist in helping me out understanding how to Like an instagram image or convert the above to post using json/php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use the [Instagram-PHP-API](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API) wrapper.
You can find an example of how to 'like' an image on [this page](https://gist.github.com/3287237).
Have also a look at the [_makeCall](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API/blob/master/instagram.class.php#L329) method of the [Instagram class](https://github.com/cosenary/Instagram-PHP-API/blob/master/instagram.class.php) for an example of how to make an API call using the [PHP cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) functions and parse the json response.